# PLaying Youtube Live Videos with in the application

Tags: android, youtube, video-streaming, youtube-api, live-streaming

I am trying to play  Youtube video's directly with in my applications in Android. If we give the direct links of the youtube like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HnbMYzdjuBs` then the device displaying different applications that can open that link after clciking the video icon. If i use `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=flowers` to fetch the links from Youtube XML services, the RTSP links are working perfectly with in the application but the quality is too bad.

How to fix this issue?

One more question is, i want to play a live video from Youtube. We have a youtube webservice to fetch the links(1,5,6 video types) of a specific vedio ID. We can use the below link to fetch the RTSP link for normal videos `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/ll4SoSJgLfI`. Which is not working for Live Videos in Youtube. i am not getting the tag `media-content`. How to show the live streaming video from youtube on android devices ?

Comment: Some how the project at the below link helped me to fix this issue. [http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/source/checkout](http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/source/checkout)